# Adicionar evento (ação) ao trocar de aba

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho uma TabPane no meu projeto que contém 3 abas diferentes, gostaria de saber como adicionar um evento ao trocar de "aba" no JavaFX.

Por exemplo, ao clicar na aba "endereço", criar um evento para eu adicionar funcionalidades para essa aba.

Pessoal, fiz assim:

Funcionou :)!

```
    @FXML private TabPane tabPane;


 tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            System.out.println("Tab Selection changed");

            labelFruto.setText(fruto.getFruto());
        }



    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um listener para cada aba, com o código abaixo:

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        //faz algo
    }
});
```

Fonte: [How can I do some action when one specific Tab is selected using Javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692062/1964435)

Comment: Olá Math, tudo bem!! Esse "Number" seria o número correspondente a "aba" selecionada? Onde eu identifico a aba que está sendo selecionada?

Comment: @SaraFernandes acredito que não, eu já trabalhei bastante com o JavaFX, entretanto não tenho instalado ele na minha máquina, vou instalar e fazer uns testes. Entretanto, acredito que você tem que pegar o objeto de cada aba dessa e escrever esse código para elas, mudando o nome do objeto onde está escrito `tabPane`. Já tentou assim? Deu algum erro?

Comment: Fiz o seguinte, criei a identificação da tab " @FXML private Tab tabCondSecagem" mas, infelizmente não está funcionando. Acredito que era para funcionar!!... Mas vou tentando aqui certo!!

Comment: Olá  Math♦, fiz como vc mencionou, mudei apenas os argumento de dentro da função  "public void changed()"... Veja acima como ficou!! E aí funcionou!! Muito obrigada pela ajuda :)!

Comment: @SaraFernandes de nada :)